# How to use callback in $http Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an service with methods that does requests to server:

```
this.add = function (data, cb) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: path
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                cb(response);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // TODO
            });
        };
```

When I call `add()` as:

```
genresService.add(function (data) {
   // TODO
});
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at successCallback (custom.js:329)
```

on line:

```
cb(response);
```

Comment: You're passing your callback as the only argument, but your function takes  two.

Comment: Rather you should user `return promise` from `this.add` function. That way you can make your function call extendable via chaining promise using `.then` over function call

Comment: As it was said above, promises should be used instead. Using callbacks in promise-based code is antipattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.add = function (data, callback,error) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: path,
        data: data
    }).then(callback).catch(error);
};
//then call like this
genresService.add(myData ,function (res) { 
      console.log(res);  
      }
    ,function(errorResponse){
       console.log(errorResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass two params in your `add` function - first is data and other is callback function. You are only passing one. You need to pass two arguments like this,

```
genresService.add( data, function (data) {
   // TODO
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'add' function expects 2 parameters : data & a callback :

```
genresService.add(data,function (response) {
   // TODO use response.data I presume
});
```

Maybe you want to do:

```
this.add = function (dataToPost, cb) {
            $http.post(path,dataToPost)
             .then(function successCallback(response) {
                cb(response.data);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // TODO
            });
        };

genresService.add(someData,function (data) {
   // TODO use data I presume
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.add = function (jsonobj, callback) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: path,
            data: jsonobj
        }).then(function(res) {
            callback(res);

        }, function(err) {
            callback(err)
        });
    };


//missing data like up : i call it jsonobj and finction got res is a callback
genresService.add(jsonobj ,function (res) { 
    console.log(res);
}
```

try it